# Pre-Order Function of BST

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am having trouble getting my `preView300` function working correctly. I know the algerithm is working correctly because I have seen other examples the exact same way. I believe its with my `findMaxNode/removeNode`functions. I have tried passing different pointer into my `findMaxNode` function but nothing that is correct.

For example: 
I insert these numbers in this order, `8,4,12,2,6,10,14,20` and call me remove function to remove `8`. I get this output  `6,4,2,12,10,14,20`. I know the `findMaxNode` is trying to do is get rid of the `8` and replace it with 20 and delete the node containing twenty and connect everything back up right.

If I can get some help on this on why this process isn't working please let me know. Also let me know if I have to add anything to this post inorder to help you.

Struct definition:

```
typedef float Element300;
struct TreeNode300;
typedef TreeNode300 * TreePtr300;
struct TreeNode300
{
    Element300 element;
    TreePtr300 left;
    TreePtr300 right;
};
```

Remove Function:

```
void BST300::remove300(const Element300 element, TreePtr300 & root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        cerr << "Error: Remove Failed!" << endl;
    }
    else if(element == root->element )
    {
        removeNode300(root);
    }
    else if(element < root->element)
    {
        remove300(element, root->left);
    }
    else
    {
        remove300(element, root->right);
    }
    return;
}
```

Remove Node function:

```
void BST300::removeNode300(TreePtr300 & root)
{
    TreePtr300 tempPointer = NULL;

    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
    {
        delete root;
        root = NULL;
    }
    else if(root->right == NULL)
    {
        tempPointer = root;
        root = root->left;
        tempPointer->left = NULL;
        delete tempPointer;
    }
    else if(root->left == NULL)
    {
        tempPointer = root;
        root = root->right;
        tempPointer->right = NULL;
        delete tempPointer;
    }
    else
    {
        findMaxNode300(root->right, tempPointer);
        root->element = tempPointer->element;
        delete tempPointer;
    }
    tempPointer = NULL;
    return;
}
```

find Maximum value function:

```
void BST300::findMaxNode300(TreePtr300 & root, TreePtr300 & tempPointer)
{
    if(root->right == NULL)
    {
        tempPointer = root;
        root = root->left;
        tempPointer->left = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        findMaxNode300(root->right, tempPointer);
    }
    return;
}
```

inView:

```
void BST300::inView300(const TreePtr300 root)const
{
    if(root)
    {
        inView300(root->left);
        cout << root->element << "-> ";
        inView300(root->right);
    }
    return;
}
```

preView:

```
void BST300::preView300(const TreePtr300 root) const
{
    if(root)
    {
        cout << root->element << "-> ";
        preView300(root->left);
        preView300(root->right);
    }
    return;
}
```

Results:

```
PREVIEW
------------------------------------------------------
Begin -> 20-> 4-> 2-> 6-> 12-> 10-> 14-> End

INVIEW
------------------------------------------------------
Begin -> 2-> 4-> 6-> 20-> 10-> 12-> 14-> End
```

Expected Results:

```
PREVIEW
------------------------------------------------------
Begin -> 20-> 4-> 2-> 6-> 12-> 10-> 14-> End

INVIEW
------------------------------------------------------
Begin -> 2.0-> 4.0-> 6-> 10-> 12-> 14-> 20 -> End
```

Binary Search Tree Original:

```
        8
    4       12
2     6    10  14
              -   20
```

Expected:

```
         20
    4       12
2     6    10  14
```

Comment: *I know the algerithm is working correctly because I have seen other examples the exact same way*  -- Just seeing other examples does not verify that your implementation works.   You actually have to test your code.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your `removeNode300` function is incorrect. When you remove a node with two children, you replace the element to be deleted with the greatest element in that branch, and delete the old-greatest node. Take this conceptual example of a tree:

```
   5
 3   7
2 4 6 8
```

Removing `5` from the tree then makes it look like:

```
   8
 3   7
2 4 6 -
```

Seven is not greater than eight, so things fall apart here.

You can either replace the node you want to delete with the greatest on the left side, or the lowest on the right. You can easily fix this right away by changing the call to `findMaxNode300` in `removeNode300`. Pass it `root->left` instead:

```
void BST300::removeNode300(TreePtr300 & root)
{
    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) {}
    else
    {
        findMaxNode300(root->left, tempPointer); //this line
    }
}
```

Obviously keep the rest of the code in, I just removed it to make this less verbose.

Comment: Thank you, for that. If I needed the biggest value from the right side I would pass in root->right? Because I have it the way you have it now. My inview is correct but my preView is not correct. Preview is `6,4,2,12,10,14,20`. Shouldn't that be starting with 20?

Comment: @Programmer12432 Did you paste the code incorrectly here? Also, I don't know what you mean by inview or preview. Is your error in a function to display the tree?

Comment: I don't believe I did. Just my preView = PreOrder.

Comment: @Programmer12432 In your code pasted here, you (incorrectly) have `root->right`. Wait, do you mean that you intend for the BST to be out of order? Starting with the highest element? Did you intend to make a priority queue? Or a heap?

Comment: I need to replace the `8` that I remove with the biggest value in the Binary Search tree. That is why I need to go to the right because the bigger values are on the right. You go to the right until the `root->right == null`

Comment: I stepped through it with my debugger. I get the right Preview when I pass in `root->right` but my inView is coming out to be `2,4,6,20,10,12,14`. So the consensus is, if I pass in `root-left` I get inView to work correctly and NOT preView. If I pass in `root-right` i get preView working and NOT inView.

Comment: @Programmer12432 Try adding the code for inView and preView.

Comment: From what I looked up they seem to be right. They are added.

Comment: @Programmer12432 You said `preView` had a problem, but posted `postView`.

Comment: Sorry about that. Been stressed on trying to get this working.

Comment: @Programmer12432 `6,4,2,12,10,14,20` is the correct output for `preView`. What are you getting instead? And can you clearly post the expected and actual results in the question itself?

Comment: There you go. Basically I need to have the 20 replace the 8 and remove the original node 20 is from as you can see if the (bad) representations of the binary trees.

Comment: @Programmer12432 Do you want to replace the `8` with a `20`, or do you want a functioning BST? The functions to display the tree work as intended. There is no other error.

Comment: Basically in the tree above 8 will be replaced with 20 so it will be 20 for the top. Then the right subtree of 14 gets sets to NULL.